# Is it possible to tell Android maps app to find path to a given coord

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to make an app that displays on a map the location of events, colleagues, appointments, etc. To this momento everything is fine, but now I was thinking of making it possible for the user to click the location and select a "guide me there" option, where it would open Android maps or another "pathfinding" app to the coords of that location. This because making a such a system on my app would surpass my capabilities and take a long time.

My question: is it possible to send an intent to Android maps to set travel to coords and if possible how?

Comment: you want to start navigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is not an offical way to start the navigator, but

```
 String address = google.navigation:q=yout+address+here;
  Intent implicitIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(address));
                                startActivity(implicitIntent);
```

has worked for me

Comment: the address you pass is like country/street name or can i use gps coords?

Comment: I used it in the countr/street way. You can try with "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude +

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks again. Also I've found you can send coord to the navigator using "google.navigation:ll=%f,%f".